# Is there an easy way to strip all markdown from a text file from the command line?

Tags: markdown

Is there an easy way to strip all markdown from a text file from the command line?

A solution that is installable with `apt` is preferable. But failing that `apt` is better than `pip` is better than `gem` is better than `npm` (for me).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install `pandoc` with:

```
$ sudo apt install pandoc
```

Next run it:

```
$ pandoc  --from markdown --to plain -o output.txt input.md
```

Comment: i get unexpected results when testing pandoc online:  `https://pandoc.org/try/?text=the+**context**+is+in+%5Bthis+link%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com)&from=markdown_strict&to=plain`